# Disable compression on partitioned index?

Tags: oracle

I'm trying to disable compression in a database, and I've been able to do so for everything except for partitioned indexes at the index level.

I've run these queries:

```
ALTER TABLE <table_name> MOVE NOCOMPRESS;

ALTER INDEX <index_name> REBUILD NOCOMPRESS;

ALTER INDEX <index_name> REBUILD PARTITION <partition_name> NOCOMPRESS;

ALTER INDEX <index_name> MODIFY PARTITION <partition_name> NOCOMPRESS;

ALTER INDEX <index_name> REBUILD SUBPARTITION <subpartition_name>;
```

To ensure that no compression is being used from the partition level downward, but the query

```
 select * from dba_indexes where compression = 'ENABLED';
```

Still returns results, and I can't use `ALTER INDEX ... REBUILD` here, because of `"ORA-14086: a partitioned index may not be rebuilt as a whole."` I was hoping that I could use something like `'ALTER INDEX ... MODIFY DEFAULT ATTRIBUTES NOCOMPRESS'`, but that doesn't seem to work.

Is there another way to disable compression at the index level without manually rebuilding each index?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Is there another way to disable compression at the index level without manually rebuilding each index?"

Had the same issue trying to change the default compression for interval partitioned indexes. The short answer is No, not for 12c database.

Got the following from someone who was (at the time) working for Oracle.

"Response from the developers is that some of the new partitioning types such as partition by reference, **automatic partition creation** depend on unparse and **inheritance is not working for compress and in memory with them because they have not yet added these attributes to unparse**.
"

https://richardfoote.wordpress.com/2016/12/06/12-2-index-advanced-compression-high-part-i-high-hopes/#comments

Comment: This is grim news, but thanks for the confirmation. I've been struggling to find a definitive answer for a few weeks now. Looks like I've got a bit of work ahead of me!

Answer (score 0):

After looking at the website noted in the answer by @garymyers I noticed on a follow-on page that there is a database parameter in 12.2 per the web page, that allows you to have index compression inherit from existing indexes at a table or tablespace level:

```
SYS@extdev02> alter system set db_index_compression_inheritance=table;
System altered.
```

Note that the parameter's value can be `tablespace` or `table`.  This is not a perfect solution as its scope is pretty wide; but it may take care of 90% of your needs.  You would still need to alter existing indexes partition by partition however; this would just affect new partition indexes.

If needed, you could put troublesome indexes in a separate tablespace and set the parameter to tablespace.

I tried doing this in Oracle 12.1 and it accepted the value, but it did not honor the setting; when adding the first index to a table with a compression value, adding additional indexes did not inherit the compression value.

For existing partition indexes, you could do something like this:

```
select 'alter index ' || INDEX_OWNER || '.' || index_name ||
       ' rebuild partition ' || PARTITION_NAME || ' NOCOMPRESS ;' 
from dba_ind_partitions 
where index_owner='SCOTT' and index_name='I_SOME_INDEX' 
and compression !='DISABLED';
```

and then invoke the output from the above query.